# Woocommerce REST API for my account & checkout process

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I'm new in WooCommerce REST API, I have worked with custom endpoints but I need some help/tutorial related to WooCommerce REST API. I have research about it but I didn't found any tutorial(s) for this.

I have got **automattic/woocommerce** and I have used below code in functions.php file:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://example.com', 
    'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
    'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v2',
    ]
);
```

but when I use this on functions file my website shows 500 server error. I don't know am I doing some wrong/foolish thing on it.

Let me know what can I do for this issue

Comment: I don't see why you'd need to use the API in PHP if it's for the same website. Are you accessing a different website via the API?

Comment: I want to use it for mobile application development

Comment: You are *way* off track. `automattic/woocommerce` is a PHP package for communicating with another website's Woocommerce REST API from within a PHP application. WooCommerce already has the API built in. You create keys in WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced and then use those keys in your application to make requests to your site's API URL.

Comment: Oh! Thanks Jacob for clearing about it, now got it. so I got reference from **https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-orders** and I can't get anything on ** print_r($woocommerce->get('orders'));** so what to do for it?

Comment: Or it's good If you are suggest some better idea how to start work on woocommerce rest api.

Comment: You said you were developing a mobile application, so why are you trying to access orders in functions.php with `$woocommerce`? Is your mobile application a PHP application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88038/discussion-between-parth-shah-and-jacob-peattie).